# Ember: Integrating Google Recaptcha with ember-cp-validations

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple contact form, with validation done using ember-cp-validations https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations and I now need to integrate the new Google Recaptcha into that.

For the rendering of the recaptcha, I am using this code - https://gist.github.com/cravindra/5beeb0098dda657433ed - which works perfectly.

However, I don't know how to deal with the verification process to allow the form to be submitted/prevented if the challenge is correct/incorrect or not provided

Here is a truncated version of my contact-form component

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Validations from './cp-validations/contact-form';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default Ember.Component.extend(Validations,{
    data:{},
    nameMessage:null,
    init() {
      this._super(...arguments);
      this.set('data',{});
     },
     actions:{
        submitForm() {

           this.validate().then(({model,validations}) => {
               if (validations.get('isValid')) {
                   // submit form
               }
               else {
                   if(model.get('validations.attrs.data.name.isInvalid')){
                this.set('nameMessage',model.get('validations.attrs.data.name.messages'));

                 }
               }
           })
        }

     }
});
```

Here is the template for the component, which includes the rendering of the recpatcha using the gist above

```
<form {{action 'submitForm' on='submit'}}>
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-6 columns">
{{input type="text" value=data.name id="name" placeholder="Enter your name"}}
<div class="error-message">
{{nameMessage}}
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="medium-12 columns">
{{google-recaptcha}}
</div>
</div>
<button class="button primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The Validations import looks like this

```
import { validator, buildValidations } from 'ember-cp-validations';
export default buildValidations({
 'data.name': {
    validators: [
      validator('presence',{
        presence:true,
        message:'Please enter your name'
      })
    ]
  },
});
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register `captchaComplete` in your `google-recaptcha` component and mix the answer with your validations

**UPDATE**

contact-form.hbs

```
<form {{action 'submitForm' on='submit'}}>
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-6 columns">
{{input type="text" value=data.name id="name" placeholder="Enter your name"}}
<div class="error-message">
{{nameMessage}}
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="medium-12 columns">
{{google-recaptcha captchaComplete=validateRecatcha}}
</div>
</div>
<button class="button primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

contact-form.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Validations from './cp-validations/contact-form';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default Ember.Component.extend(Validations,{
    data:{},
    nameMessage:null,
    captchaValidated: false,
    init() {
      this._super(...arguments);
      this.set('data',{});
     },
     actions:{
        validateRecatcha(data){
            //if data denotes captcha is verified set captchaValidated to true else false
        },
        submitForm() {

           this.validate().then(({model,validations}) => {
               if (validations.get('isValid') && this.get('captchaValidated')) {
                   // submit form
               }
               else {
                   if(model.get('validations.attrs.data.name.isInvalid')){
                this.set('nameMessage',model.get('validations.attrs.data.name.messages'));

                 }
               }
           })
        }

     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back - sorry I'm not clear on this. I see from the recaptcha component I need to deal with the captchaComplete action in the parent component (contact-form) or route - but I'm not getting anywhere with this - have you any more guidance? Many thanks!

Comment: Many thanks for getting back - sorry for the delay - I will check this out shortly - really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Hi,  I've given this a go. The action validateRecaptcha (or should it be captchaComplete as I thought this is being sent from the google-recpatcha component?) in contact-form.js is not getting called so I can't set captchaValidate?

Comment: @Newfoundland According to gist link you sent for recaptcha, that component send two actions : `captchaComplete` and `captchaExpired`. So if you set (register) these actions when putting recaptcha component `{{google-recaptcha}}` those actions in your controller or component called.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. I have registered captchaComplete, and this calls validateRecaptcha in contact-form.js, but if I console.log and force captchaValidated to be true, nothing is logged and the form still won't submit ... sorry about this!

Comment: @Newfoundland you should check if recaptcha validation is valid or not in `validateRecaptcha` and set `captchaValidated` property to true or false

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back - sorry for late reply - I am able to trigger validateRecaptcha in contact-form.js by doing this in the contact-form template captchaComplete=(action "validateRecaptcha")} as opposed to captchaComplete = validateRecaptcha .. I'll look again as soon as I can

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help - have got it working now - much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I've got everything working - including the reset function. The problem is that the reset doesn't like the ember id which is generated in the mark up (eg ember853). So, as this id is optional I've removed it . in the resetGrecaptha method grecaptcha.reset(). This is perfect if you arrive at the contact page when you visit the app, but not if arrive from another page. In this case, the code generates an error stating " Uncaught Error: Invalid ReCAPTCHA client id: undefined" ... when the client id is an optional field !!! Any ideas? Many thanks!